# Trying to get the correct result using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to separate the results of a regex query into groups. almost all the results are as I want, however in some situations I can’t capture the data correctly.

**REGEX:**

```
(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})[\.\d ]*\s([\s\D]*).*\s([\d]+,\d{2})\s([CD])
```

**EXAMPLE TEXT:**

```
01/01/2021 555.555.88.6 TESTE A IMPOSTOS 00.05.5 1500,00 D
01/02/2021 555.555.88.6 HISTORICO ALEATORIO 1800,00 C
03/03/2021 555.555.88.6 RECEITAS A PRAZO 300,00 D
04/05/2021 555.555.88.6 VENDAS A VISTA 1500,00 D 1,52 C
```

**RESULT OBTAINED:**

```
(01/01/2021) (TESTE A IMPOSTOS) (1500,00) (D)
(01/02/2021) (HISTORICO ALEATORIO) (1800,00) (C)
(03/03/2021) (RECEITAS A PRAZO) (300,00) (D)
(04/05/2021) (VENDAS A VISTA) (1,52) (C)
```

**EXPECTED OUTCOME:**

```
(01/01/2021) (TESTE A IMPOSTOS) (1500,00) (D)
(01/02/2021) (HISTORICO ALEATORIO) (1800,00) (C)
(03/03/2021) (RECEITAS A PRAZO) (300,00) (D)
(04/05/2021) (VENDAS A VISTA) (1500,00) (D)
```

In the examples above I tried to make clear the results obtained in each group within "(GROUP X)". ;P

Basically the line of the text that still gives me a problem is the last one: "04/05/2021 555.555.88.6 SELL SALES 1500.00 D 1.52 C"

**My efforts can be seen more clearly at:** https://regex101.com/r/YQVQbc/1

Comment: your example text doesnt match the one in your regex101 link right now. the first, 3rd and 4th line or different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples/attempts, could you please try following.

```
(^(?:\d{2}\/){2}\d{4})\s+\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{2}\.\d\s+(.*?)(?:\d{2}.\d{2}\.\d)?\s+(\d{3,4},\d{2})\s+([a-zA-Z]+)
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/cbsz1X/2/)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
(                               ##Creating 1st capturing group here.
  ^(?:\d{2}\/){2}               ##checking from starting of value, in a non-capturing group matching 2 digits followed by / and this should be matched with 2 occurrences.
  \d{4}                         ##Matching 4 digits here.
)                               ##Closing 1st capturing group here.
\s+\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{2}\.\d\s+   ##Matching spaces 3 digits dot 3 digits dot 2 digits dot 1 digit with spaces.
(.*?)                           ##Creating 2nd capturing which has non greedy value till next mentioned match in it.
(?:\d{2}.\d{2}\.\d)?            ##In a non-capturing group matching 2 digits dot 2 digits dot followed by digit and keeping this group as optional.
\s+                             ##Matching 1 or more spaces occurrences here.
(\d{3,4},\d{2})                 ##Creating 3rd capturing group which has 3 to 4 digits occurrences comma followed by 2 digits.
\s+                             ##Matching 1 or more spaces occurrences here.
([a-zA-Z]+)                     ##Creating 4th capturing group which has rest of value till end of value.
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment ;). This regex solves one of the problems that was obtaining the correct value in the 3th. but on the 4th the expected result would be (D), I now get it (D 1,52 C)

Comment: @FoioLag, sure, I have updated my regex now, could you please do check it once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Perfect. problem solved. thank you so much

Comment: @FoioLag, your welcome, cheers and happy learning 

Answer (score 2):

The pattern isn't matching the first line because there needs to be a check for the optional group of digits ("00.05.5") that appears there. This is most easily done with a group that is itself marked as optional. To make the output of groups match what you are wanting, you can mark this optional group as atomic so it won't count as a captured value.

```
(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}) [\d.]* ([A-Z ]*) (?>[\d.]+ )*(\d+,\d{2}) ([CD])
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SjNmWJ/1)

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, this answer will also help me. :) This shows me a new concept in the regex.